# Find wether hibernate entity column(field member) is nullable at runtime

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, metadata

I have a problem where I would like to find that a field of a hibernate entity(by `entityClass`) is representing nullable column or not.

However I want to get it using reliable hibernate meta not like checking for `@NotNull` annotations and trying to cover any possible scenarios of hibernate considering an entity field nullable or not seems not very reliable.

Appreciate your kind help.

Comment: See this: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html#getPropertyNullability()  I am sure you will manage.

Comment: @krokodilko 10x a lot it worked just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@krokodilko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2568341/krokodilko) I provide the solution code:

```
protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory().unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}
```

Get nullable metadata

```
Map<String, Boolean> entityPropNullables = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
// Provide the class of disired metadata as parameter
ClassMetadata entityMeta = getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(anEntityClass);
String[] propNames = entityMeta.getPropertyNames();
boolean[] isNullableProps = entityMeta.getPropertyNullability();

if (propNames != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < propNames.length; i++ ) {
        entityPropNullables.put(propNames[i], isNullableProps[i]);
    }
}
```